# Why do go module versions sometimes need 2 lines in go.sum

Tags: go, go-modules

Why do individual module versions sometimes need 2 lines in `go.sum`?

- one line is just for the module version (`v0.1.1` in the example below)
- one line also has `/go.mod` tacked onto the version (`v0.1.1/go/mod` in the example below).

For example:

```
github.com/foo/bar v0.1.1 h1:kDgnGXZpvZUi7ym6Rm23yVn3gRqBag+vU6M/wytZR9c=
github.com/foo/bar v0.1.1/go.mod h1:MZcarCLffCxoj/EF1yhRb4HvOSmCkm5Z8FPmzWrMG+g=
```

The reason I ask is because sometimes when I `go get` a package, an indirect dependency will be generated in `go.sum` with only the second line from the example above, and then the build will fail with `410 gone` for that package@version. However if I manually `go get` the indirect dependency, the build no longer fails with `410 gone`.

I believe this only happens with private repositories, so I understand it will not play well with sum.golang.org. However, I'd like to figure out if it's possible to avoid getting the 410 in the first place, especially with regards to automated module updates, etc.

Comment: Read the go.sum section in https://golang.org/ref/mod#authenticating. the v0.1.1/go.mod is the hash for the go.mod file itself while the other is for the "source code". The problem you see has nothing to do with two lines being present.

Comment: Thanks for the reply @Volker. Sorry that my question was unclear. I understand the difference between the two lines. But I don't understand why `go get` will get insufficient information to build indirect dependencies, yet if I `go get` the indirect dependency directly, it will get sufficient information to perform the build. Interestingly enough, even if not directly caused by one line being present, the problem is indeed solved by the two lines being present, hence the phrasing of my question.

Comment: `go get` will get the latest version by default, which may be different from the one required by your dependency. We can't really help you without seeing the exact commands that fail.

Comment: This may be a bug in the `go` command. If you still see it with `go1.16rc1`, please open a new issue (with steps to reproduce) at https://golang.org/issue/new.

Answer (score 4):

The `v0.1.1/go.mod` entry contains the checksum for the `go.mod` file in isolation. That is needed to ensure consistency any time you are loading or changing dependencies.

The `v0.1.1` entry (without the `/go.mod` suffix) contains the checksum for the full source code of the module, including all of the `.go` source files for the packages within it.

The two parts are downloaded separately so that you don't need to download the full source code for dependencies that you don't intend to build or test (a fairly common situation for projects with casual contributors). But because the `go` command downloads them separately, it needs separate checksums for them.